# Simple Projectile Movement

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a projectile fire AFTER the Spacebar has been pressed however the way I've implemented it only seems to fire WHILE the Spacebar is pressed down. I thought of perhaps creating a for-loop or while-loop but through my knowledge learned so far, I can't see that working either.

The code below is what I've implemented:

```
if (state->IsKeyDown(Input::Keys::SPACE))
{
    _projectile->_position->Y -= _projectile->_speed * elapsedTime;
}
```

Not actually sure what is wrong with this only that it acts upon the pressing and holding of the Spacebar rather than just the pressing of the Spacebar

Comment: There isn't enough information in your post, at least for me, to suggest anything useful.

Comment: Do you mean you want a pause between pressing space and firing, or it should keep firing even after spave is released?

Comment: good example of what you need - > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: When firing (i.e. at the space key-press) you *create* the projectile object. And then update its position in the event loop until it hits something, when you destroy the object. If you want to have multiple projectiles flying at the same time, have a collection of them that you put the object in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if`-clause is no longer executed once you've lifted the space bar, so you need to update the projectile *outside* the condition.  However, you can't do it unconditionally either because you don't want to update a projectile before you've hit the space bar.

So the solution here is to have a boolean state variable to keep track of whether the space bar has been pressed (call this `projectile_launched`, for example).  Initialize this to `false` because presumably there is no projectile at the beginning of the game.

Once you have that, the `if`-clause needs to be changed to:

```
if (state->IsKeyDown(Input::Keys::SPACE))
{
    projectile_launched = true;
}
```

which will activate the projectile.  Then add an additional `if`-clause `projectile_launched` in your *rendering loop*:

```
if (projectile_launched) {
    _projectile->_position->Y -= _projectile->_speed * elapsedTime;
}
```

This will allow the projectile to be updated at every frame of your game.  Note that you will probably want deactivate `projectile_launched` later on when the projectile reaches the edge of the environment.

Furthermore, what I've shown here only works for a *single* projectile.  You can't have more than one of them at a time.  To support multiple projectiles, you will need, instead of a boolean variable, a *list* of projectiles (using, for example, `std::vector`) that you will continuously keep track of and update at every frame.

Comment: you said this would only work with a single projectile. If you was to create an array of projectiles and access it's elements individually. Do you think that would work?